# Checking to make sure a column has been updated in the last 5 days SQL

Tags: sql

I'm looking for the best possible way to check to make sure a column of dates, in a SQL database, have been updated in the last 5 days.

For example: The column contains 100 dates, all ranging from 1/1/2017 to 4/10/2017. Today is 4/19/2017. I'm looking at all of these dates and checking to see if any of them have been within the last 5 days of today, if not throw an exception/error/anything. Mainly I'm checking to see if this column is being updated regularly.

Thank you.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a query and return a value

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 'OKAY' else 'NO UPDATES !!!' end)
from t
where datecol >= current_timestamp - interval '5 day';
```

This will work in more updates.

But, actually, I would probably do the logic in the application:

```
select max(datecol) as max_datecol
from t;
```

Then do the logic in the application based on the recency of the last update.

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many entries have been added in last 5 days.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE date_column > NOW() - 5 DAYS;
```

Then in the application just check:

```
if (result > 0) { there has been a new entry in last 5 days } 
else {ther has not been a new entry in last 5 days}
```